# Change class of disabled tab on change of dropdown value

Tags: java, jquery, css, wicket, wicket-6

I have 1 dropdown and based on dropdown value tab will be enable or disable. By default I am using getTabContainerCssClass() for all tab and it will show all tab as enable view but i want to change a tab css class as it look like to be disable after change the dropdown value.

```
DropDownChoice ProductDropDown = new DropDownChoice("ProductList", new PropertyModel(this, "SupplierProduct"),ProductList, new choiceRenderer("name","id"));
add(supplierProductDropDown);

supplierProductDropDown.add(new AjaxFormComponentUpdatingIndicatingBehavior("onchange"){
            @Override
            protected void onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
                 /* do some code for changing dropdown */
            }
      });

tabs = new ArrayList<AbstractTab>();

/* provide some tab details */

tab = new AjaxTabbedPanel("tabs", tabs){

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        protected String getTabContainerCssClass() {
            return "producttab-row";
        }
        @Override
        protected WebMarkupContainer newLink(String linkId, final int index) {

            return new Link(linkId)
            {
                    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

                    public void onClick() {
                            setSelectedTab(index);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean isEnabled() {
                        if(index == 1 && /*drop down condition that will be disable the tab*/){
                            /*I want to change css of this tab*/
                            return false;
                        }
                        else{
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
            }
       }
}
```

Any Idea about this ......

UPDATE: after updating the code

```
 @Override
                    protected void onComponentTag(final ComponentTag tag) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        super.onComponentTag(tag);
                        if(/*Dropdown condition*/){

                             tag.append("class", "disabletab", " ");
                         }
}
```

But it didn't worked on this. Please help

SOLUTION : I have Override onComponentTag in AjaxTabbedPanel.see below code

```
tabs = new ArrayList<AbstractTab>();

/* provide some tab details */

tab = new AjaxTabbedPanel("tabs", tabs){

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    protected String getTabContainerCssClass() {
        return "producttab-row";
    }
@Override
            protected void onComponentTag(final ComponentTag tag)
            {
            super.onComponentTag(tag);

            String cssClass = tag.getAttribute("class");
            if (cssClass == null)
            {
                cssClass = " ";
            }
            /*check condition and change css classname*/
            tag.put("class", cssClass.trim());
        }
}
```

Comment: look like  not updating properly

Comment: @soorapadman I didnt get your point. Please tell me where i am wrong

Comment: I assume Onchange of dropdown you are changing the tabbed panel . In order to change in tabs using  Ajax event U should have update the component using `target.add ` some thing like that , Since you shared less code i can't get whats the exact issue.

Comment: @soorapadman I want to change of css class of tab dynamically. previously i am using getTabContainerCssClass() for calling css class which is tab inherit property of css class "enabletab" in this method and it will be applicable for all tab but now i want disable 1 tab so css sholud be changed, so i have write code disable the tab but not able to change css class... By default tab is taking default class name as tab0, tab1, tab2 and tab3 and all are inherited property of "enabletab". Suppose I have to disable tab1 and class should be "disabletab" instead of tab1 in markup after render the page

Comment: @soorapadman I hope it will clear my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should override `Link#onComponentTag(ComponentTag)` method and set the CSS class with: `tag.append("class", "dynamicValueDependingOnDropDownsModel", " ")`.

Comment: dynamicValueDependingOnDropDownsModel should be dynamaic class name which is i want to changed.

Comment: Hi Martin-g i have update my question with your suggestion but didnt work. Please help.

Comment: Hi @martin-g  i have update my question with your suggestion but didnt work. Please help.